# Access Outlook IMAP with OAuth token

Tags: ios, oauth, outlook, imap

I'm attempting to connect to Outlook via IMAP, using credentials obtained via OAuth 2.0. I've been using [Microsoft's guide to this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440163.aspx).

OAuth seems to go fine. I use the token endpoint described in that document (`https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf`), with the `wl.imap` and `wl.offline_access` scopes as described. I go through the process in my app and get an OAuth token. I'm using an `outlook.com` email address.

But when I connect to `imap-mail.outlook.com` and attempt to authenticate, it's rejected with a simple `2 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.` I've verified that the `AUTHENTICATE` call matches the documented requirements, including the user email address and a properly formatted token.

The IMAP conversation is as follows:

```
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [QgBOADYAUABSADEAMQBDAEEAMAAwADQAOQAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADEAMQAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
1 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
1 OK CAPABILITY completed.
2 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 [redacted, but verified]
2 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

I expect I'm getting the wrong OAuth endpoint or the wrong scopes, but don't know yet. Can anyone help with this?

In case it makes a difference, this is for an iPhone app.